# Reactjs closure issue with event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I'm new to Reactjs and I'm working on one project.

A typical scenario I'm facing is the handling of events, and values storing inside variables:

```
let counter = 0;

function clickHandler() {
  counter++;
}
```

For as absurd as it can appear, all the time I use this pattern in reactjs I get `counter undefined`, the only way I can turn around this is to put the `counter` inside a `state`. I tried a PoC in *codesandbox* and everything works, so I'm getting crazy trying to understand the reason of this weird behaviour.

Then my question: is there any typical react scenario which cause a function/handler to not see its closure correctly?

Comment: You should use [React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: Can you provide a min repro example in code sandbox?

Comment: The code here, out of context, cannot produce that error. It's important to provide enough context to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way of doing this in react will be to use state.
Check the useState hook documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  
  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter + 1)
  
  return (
    <button onClick={incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
  )
}
```